# Triangle Positioning

Tags: html, css

**Hello I want to achieve similar to this image.**

[image]

Here is my css code

```
*{
    background:#444;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.display{
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background:green;
    position:fixed;
}
.one{
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    margin-top:-200px;
    background:red;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.two{
    width:100%;
    height:450px;
    margin-top:200px;
    background:blue;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

I've try to achieve similar positioning here is my Code is [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/vgzqcnkt)

**My question is** - What could you suggest me to achieve similar positioning?

Is it good to use transform for 4 div images and positioning them?

Comment: I don't think you linked to the right fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is a background, let's simplify it with a single HTML element.

- Top and bottom background colors are a single gradient with two colors
- left and right background colors are `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements rotated with `transform: rotate`
- The before and after pseudo elements get `z-index: 1`. Elements that should be above them get `position: relative` and `z-index: 2`

### Example

```css
body {
  background: #212121;
}
div {
  background: #F00;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #EB1249 0%, #EB1249 50%, #251F39 50%, #251F39 100%);
  margin: 0 auto;
}
div:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -70%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: #fce4ec;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -59.3%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: #F5B8A2;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy if you set the `transform-origin` to the corners of your boxes.  Basically, instead of rotating from the middle, you can rotate from the corner.  So You'd have two boxes at, for instance:

```
right  : 200px;
bottom : 200px;
transform-origin : 100% 100%;
```

one rotated 45deg, the other -45deg.  Then the other two at `190, 210` or whatever.  Note that you also need `-webkit-transform-origin`, `-ms-transform-origin`, `-moz-transform-origin`, `-o-transform-origin`